# Pass a Python list to the ORDER BY clause of a SQL Server query

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to pass a python list to a SQL Server query. I am having trouble with pyobdc errors.

I have tried the following:

```
# order_by is a list with 80 strings e.g. ['a','b','c', ...]
placeholders = ", ".join(["?"] * len(order_by))
query = """
     SELECT *
     FROM my_table_name
     ORDER BY (""" + placeholders + ")"
cursor.execute(query, order_by)
```

It's giving me a pyodbc error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','. (102)

I can not figure out where I did a syntax error

Comment: Concatenating strings like this is how SQL Injection attacks happen. This code is wrong for *any* database - MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server. In fact, it would fail in the same way in any of those databases. In general, you should use a parameterized/server-bound query instead

Comment: If you want to find what the actual error is, inspect the `query` string. For starters, there's no need for parentheses in `ORDER BY`. Second, *80* columns probably points to a design flaw - does the table *really* contain *more* than 80 columns? And do you really need to order by all of them? Third, why is that variable named `placeholders` ? An `ORDER BY` clause contains column names, not values or parameters (which can only supply values)

Comment: Hi, so the ORDER BY list actually was obtained from another sql insert that retrieved all the column names of the same table first

Comment: What is the query string? *That's* what contains the syntax error.

Comment: It's not a design flaw, it was uploaded from a .csv file

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME,*
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' and TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name'

Comment: it is then, because order doesn't matter. And `", ".join(["?"] * len(order_by))` creates question marks, not column names

Comment: The order_by list I made from the column name looks fine so I am confident the retrieval of column names was okay

Comment: That list is invalid. ORDER BY expects a list of columns. ` placeholders` contains `?, ?, ?` instead. Table and column names aren't *values* so they can't be passed as parameters.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if this sounds stupid but I am under the impression that I am passing a list of 80 '?'s and then replacing them with the column names from the order_by list when I am executing the cursor.

Comment: Basically I want all the columns of a SQL table to be sorted. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As I said, column and table names aren't values, so they can't be parameters. Assuming `order_by` contains the column names, use `placeholders = ", ".join(order_by)`.

Comment: placeholders = ", ".join(order_by)
cursor.execute("""
     SELECT *
     FROM my_table_name
     ORDER BY ?""" % placeholders)

I tried this but unfortunately it gives an error saying not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: A database server (any one) doesn't just execute a SQL *string*. It uses the indexes, statistics on the queries and columns involved in a query to generate an query execution plan, similar to how a compiler uses a type to create executable code. Parameters are the same as parameters in a program. They are used to provide values, not change the types of the program itself

Comment: inspect the query to see what's wrong. For starters, it shouldn't contain *any* question marks in ORDER BY. `SELECT * FROM my_table_name ORDER BY a,b,c,d` will work just fine.

Comment: but this will be a variable. I can not fix this to be 4/6/80 column names.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table_name ORDER BY a,b,c,d` works. `SELECT * FROM my_table_name ORDER BY ?,?,?,?` doesn't. You don't fix anything either - you can only know the number of columns if you know what table you're targeting. If you do that, you know the names as well.

Comment: Assuming there's a real need for ordering across *all* columns and you don't want to use the column names even when you know them, you can use `ORDER BY 1,2,3,4` which order the results by the columns that appear in the SELECT clause by position

Comment: Unfortunately ordering by all columns is a requirement. I do understand what you said. I will not know the column names upfront so that will always be a variable.

Comment: You already said that you *do* know the names up front, that's what you show in the code `a list with 80 strings ` and what you said in the comment with the query that loads the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Even if you don't know the column names, you need to know their *count*

Comment: In any case, `?` won't work in an ORDER BY column. There's no way around that. Column names will work. Numbers will work. To troubleshoot a SQL statement, try running the query itself, not the python code that creates the query

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Interesting to note that you want a list of column names for the ORDER BY clause of your `my_table_name` query, so you run a query against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` but *that* query has no ORDER BY. So, you are essentially pulling a list of the columns *in some arbitrary order* and using that as the ORDER BY for the `my_table_name` query,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters are only used for passing column *values*, not column *names*. In cases where you need to dynamically include object names you need to use Dynamic SQL (string substitution), e.g., something like this:

```python
schema_name = 'dbo'
table_name = 'Donor'

sql = """\
SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=? AND TABLE_NAME=?
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
"""
crsr.execute(sql, schema_name, table_name)
columns = ', '.join([x[0] for x in crsr.fetchall()])
sql = f"SELECT * FROM [{schema_name}].[{table_name}] ORDER BY {columns}"

print(sql)
# SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Donor] ORDER BY [id], [last_name], [first_name]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you Gord.